# hibernate mapping for oracle long raw

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I try to create a hibernate mapping for an oracle database. The datebase is pretty old from before  oracle 8 but is now on 10. Hibernate reverse engineering balks at a long raw column. This datatype is deprecated and should be converted to blob.

But this is not my database. If the customer refuses to convert how would a hibernate mapping look like ?

Comment: Did you try to map it manually to anything? I guess you should be able to map it to java.sql.Blob; If you that fails, you must be able to map it to a UserType. see this http://blog.xebia.com/2009/11/understanding-and-writing-hibernate-user-types/

Comment: I've just googled it and it according to Hibernate team member steve, it is possible to map it to String. link: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2203393&sid=a5c018868dabdb11ca878fb30946ce19

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try mapping it to `byte[]`.

If you get `java.sql.SQLException: Stream has already been closed`, then try setting `useFetchSizeWithLongColumn = true` in the connection properties for the `OJDBC` driver. See the [OracleDriver API](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver.html)